# Add 5 Class Randomly But not at the begining

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i'm working on a project it's a simple balloon game. But i have some modification i'm giving a simple example with `<ul> <li>`

```
<ul class="balloons">
  <li class="image1" id="b_1">1</li> <!--it can  be any class but i do not want it to add at beginning  -->
  <li class="image4" id="b_2">2</li>
  <li class="image5" id="b_3">3</li>
  <li class="image3" id="b_4">4</li>
  <li id="b_5">5</li>
  <li id="b_6">6</li> 
  <li class="image2" id="b_7">7</li>
  <li id="b_8">8</li> <!--any possibilities to add after this ? -->
  <li id="b_9">9</li>
  <li id="b_10">10</li>
  <li id="b_11">11</li>
  <li id="b_12">12</li>
  <li id="b_13">13</li>
  <li id="b_14">14</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var size_baloon = $(".balloons li").size();

        var images = ["","image1", "image2","image3","image4","image5"];

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            var randomebloon = Math.floor((Math.random() * size_baloon));

            //var randomebloon=randomebloon+1;

            var listofbloon = $('#b_' + randomebloon);
            //listofbloon.addClass('pwb');

            listofbloon.addClass(images[i]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code adding the class randomly but at adding at very beginning sometime which i do not want. Any help?

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to specifically state what you want the code to do? As I read the question I'm lost as to your expectations and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one. Always picks unique 5 items except the ones you define in exclude array.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/0nogjpwL/

**snippet**

```js
var exclude = [0, 1, 2, 10];
var arr = [];
while (arr.length < 5) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    if (arr.includes(randomnumber) || exclude.includes(randomnumber)) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
$("li").filter(function(index) {
    if (arr.includes(index)) {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color": "red"
        }).addClass("image" + arr.indexOf(index));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will try and let you know.

Comment: I changed your code according to my need this works  i do not need the filter.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could get a random number between `min` and `max` :

```
var max = size_baloon; //max in your case id your 'size_baloon'
var min = 8; //Since you want the numbers plus than 8

var randomebloon = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
```

So `randomebloon` will be always between your min and max variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer this code works but it adds class some times <li class="image1 image4 image3"> which i do not want and also skips the class as well eg. image2 class was not added in the list.

Comment: You're welcome, so try to use `listofbloon.prop('class',images[i])` instead.

Comment: No it removes the existing class which breaks the functionality .